# Why using kableExtra library wrongly formats output of RMarkdown to Word

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

If I uncomment `kableExtra` library the Word output becomes wrongly formatted but `html`output is always right. Is `kableExtra` compatible with knitting to Word?

---

### title: "kableExtra2Word"
output:
word_document: default
html_document: default

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
#library(kableExtra)
library(janitor)
```

```
MT <- tibble(Session = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
              scores = rep('Not', 10),
              B_A = rep('A', 10))
```

```
t <- MT %>%
    tabyl(Session, scores, B_A, show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>%
    adorn_totals(where = "col")
kable(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kableExtra` doesn't seem to be compatible with Word output, you may try other alternatives. Example - `flextable::regulartable`

````
```{r}
MT <- tibble(Session = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
              scores = rep('Not', 10),
              B_A = rep('A', 10))
t <- MT %>%
    tabyl(Session, scores, B_A, show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>%
    adorn_totals(where = "col")
flextable::regulartable(t$A)
````

[image]